# How can I find the oldest folder in a node directory?

Tags: node.js, express, timestamp, fs

I am trying to find the oldest folder in a directory of my nodejs app.
Right now I get the folder names by `fs.readdirSync` and the I try to run through the `mtime`  in a for-loop with the `fs.stat` function. But it does not return any values.

```
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  folders = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/uploads/');
  var oldestTime;
  var oldest;

  for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    let stats = fs.statSync(folders[i]);
    if (oldestTime == undefined || stats.mtime < oldestTime) {
      oldestTime = stats.mtime;
      oldest = folders[i];
    }
  }
  console.log("oldest folder name is:", oldest)
}
```

Is there a better way?
Thank you so much!

Comment: You have the right procedure. Show some code? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: okay I updated my question, does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the asynchronous version of fs.stat(). Try the synchronous (callback-free) fs.statSync() instead.

And don't forget that readdir returns results named `.` for the current directory and `..` for the parent directory. You may want to exclude those from your mtime search.

And please spend some time reading up on the Javascript asynchronous programming model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I still don't get why my code above kind of sucks in the fs.ststSync() function. It does not give me any log..

Answer (score 0):

```
folders = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/uploads");
var oldestTime;
var oldest;

for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    let stats = fs.statSync(__dirname + "/uploads/" + folders[i]);
    if (oldestTime == undefined || stats.mtime < oldestTime) {
        oldestTime = stats.mtime;
        oldest = folders[i];
    }
}
console.log("oldest folder name is:", oldest)
```

or use sort to get the oldest one:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const cron = require("cron");
var job = new cron.CronJob('* * * * * *', function () {
    const folders = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + "/uploads");
    var oldest = folders.sort((a, b) => fs.statSync(__dirname + '/uploads/' + a).mtime - fs.statSync(__dirname + '/uploads/' + b).mtime)[0];
    console.log("oldest folder name is:", oldest)
});
job.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I should have said that I am using this in a node-cron schedule. Your code does not log anything when I try it... I updated the code again..

Comment: @papafredo6 statSync path should add prefix